# C# - Adding emoticons into a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am currently creating a side project that deals with dual-user communication using DuplexChanneling in C#.

My problem is the implementation of this very simple, yet tedious aspect--emotes.

Here is the code that is giving me trouble:

```
Hashtable emotions;

    void CreateEmotions()
    {
        emotions = new Hashtable(6);
        emotions.Add(":)", ChattingClient.Properties.Resources.regular_smile);
        emotions.Add(":(", ChattingClient.Properties.Resources.sad_smile);            
    }

    void AddEmotions()
    {
        foreach (string emote in emotions.Keys)
        {
            while (TextBoxDisplay1.Text.Contains(emote))
            {
                int ind = TextBoxDisplay1.Text.IndexOf(emote);
                TextBoxDisplay1.Select(ind, emote.Length);
                Clipboard.SetImage((Image)emotions[emote]);
                TextBoxDisplay1.Paste();
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is because 
`Clipboard.SetImage((Image)emotions[emote]);`

It states both:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Clipboard.SetImage(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource)' has some invalid arguments

and

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource'  C:\Users\StandardGuy\Desktop\ChattingApplication\ChattingClient\ChattingClient\MainWindow.xaml.cs   68  41  ChattingClient

Comment: Check that you imported the correct library for the Image object.

Comment: Consider just [using Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block)).  WPF supports them inline with text, so you can just add a palate to insert them into the message ☺.  If you want color, there are multicolor fonts for that on Windows 8.1 and above.

Comment: @Mitch, that sounds like a good idea but I wanted to go for a more 00's ilk chat client with MSN style emotes. Kinda my niche I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Import the namespaces to use BitmapImage and Uri
- Using the Solution Explorer go to the Resources folder of the project, then go to the properties of each image and set the **Build Action** to **Resources**

```
Hashtable emotions;

void CreateEmotions()
{
    emotions = new Hashtable(6);
    emotions.Add(":)", new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/name_of_picture1.png", UriKind.Relative)));
    emotions.Add(":(", new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/name_of_picture2.png", UriKind.Relative)));
}

void AddEmotions()
{
    foreach (string emote in emotions.Keys)
    {
        while (TextBoxDisplay1.Text.Contains(emote))
        {
            int ind = TextBoxDisplay1.Text.IndexOf(emote);
            TextBoxDisplay1.Select(ind, emote.Length);
            Clipboard.SetImage((BitmapImage)emotions[emote]);
            TextBoxDisplay1.Paste();
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How does one import the namespaces? Is it the same as .NET objects in the resource folder?

Comment: At the top of the file of the code you posted just make sure you have "using System;" and "using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;"

Comment: still seems to be prompting the error. But I'll keep trying.

Comment: Thank you for your support, but it is still giving me the same error for the clipboard.

Comment: Did you remove the cast for '(Image)emotions[emote]'?

Comment: yes and  I even added your new edition--the urikind, also added the namespaces

Comment: Hmm, try "Clipboard.SetImage((BitmapImage)emotions[emote])", otherwise I don't know what else is wrong

Comment: It works, the code part of it. But now the picture of the emoticon is not even being printed.

Comment: I think Textbox only supports strings, try using a [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The documentation for RichTextbox states, "While RichTextBox supports copying and **pasting of images**, certain scenarios are currently unsupported and may not work properly. The following table summarizes these scenarios and expected results." However if you use RichTextBox you might have to make changes to your code